# How to Create a Shiny Colour Swatch Puddle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

I was wondering how you would create something like this:

[image: puddle of color]
<sup>Source: [orlybeauty.com](http://www.orlybeauty.com/)</sup>

As you can see, there is a shadow in the bottom left, which gets lighter as you move diagonally to the top right. There is also a fleck of white added, which is very easy to apply.

I had a go myself, using a linear gradient, with about 75% opacity either side and nothing in the centre. It didn't work!

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: So it is not the marble-effect you are after, but rather the button-effect? If so, there are a million tutorials out there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fairly easy to recreate the bevel effect. The inner swirl is a bit more difficult.

I created the swirl with several variations of `Filter > Render > Clouds` set to `Multiply` and then merged with a solid color. Then used `Filter > Oil Paint...` to add some additional swirl variations. And finally `Filter > Distort > Twirl` and `Filter > Blur > Radial Blur` to create the twist appearance.

I did this on a couple layers and used some blending between the layers to add some depth to the overall swirl effect.

From there it's a fairly simple matter to use `Layer > Layer Style > Bevel & Emboss...` and adjust settings to create the shine and shadow of the "button" effect. I actually used two layers for the Bevel & Emboss (with the Fill Opacity set to 0% so only the effect shows through) and used color burn and screen on one and multiply and screen on the second.

[image: swirl]

[image: construct]

This isn't perfect, but your original image was a photograph of a drop of what appears to be fingernail polish with the bevel layer style added to the photo. It wasn't created entirely in Photoshop. You could simply photograph a drop of fingernail polish yourself, then ad the bevel effect to enhance the depth as someone did to your sample image.

You could also overlay a photo on top of any creation to add some appearance with that....

[image: with photo overlay]

Comment: This is an amazing answer, thank you so much!